# IE Conditionals for Javascript

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scale, opacity

I am running into issues with IE support for dynamic opacity and scaling using jQuery `.animate()`. I would like to change these specific lines that IE has issues with while still leaving them the "original" way in Chrome and Firefox.

I have cam accross a solution that uses `<!-- [if IE]>` qrapped around a `<script>` tag. My problem is I want to use a line specific IE conditional in various places inside of a .JS file.

Is there a solution to this issue, or do I need to create an IE version of my .JS file?

Answer (score 4):

You can always use jQuery to make browser dependent check...

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
   //IE
} else {
   //NOT IE
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the code you suggested, and am running into a small kink. The browser does read the IE script first, but then loads the non-IE script right after. Any suggeastions? My code is below:

Comment: if ($.browser.msie) {
  alert("IE");
} else {

function waitingZoom() {
    alert("not IE");
    $("#picture").animate({ scale: 4, translateX: -1000, translateY: -1200, opacity: 0 }, 850, "easeInExpo");
  }
}

Comment: move function outside the check, and call it inside the check

Comment: function waitingZoom() {alert("not IE");/*animation here...*/} $.browser.msie ? alert("IE") : waitingZoom();

Comment: @KCP now you can vote, also be sure to mark his answer checked as the solution to your problem :-)